# windsor nHibernate ISession

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, castle-windsor, castle

I have a MVC5 application and set my hibernate stuff up like that:

```
  public class PersistenceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {


        container.Register(

            //Nhibernate session factory
            Component.For<ISessionFactory>().UsingFactoryMethod(CreateNhSessionFactory).LifeStyle.Singleton,


            Component.For<ISession>().UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).LifestylePerWebRequest(),

            //All repoistories
            Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HdtRepository))).InSameNamespaceAs<HdtRepository>().WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestyleTransient()




            );
    }
```

and my base repository looks like that:

```
  public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : Entity<TPrimaryKey>
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the NHibernate session object to perform database operations.
    /// </summary>
    public ISession Session { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Used to get a IQueryable that is used to retrive object from entire table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IQueryable to be used to select entities from database</returns>
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Session.Query<TEntity>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Primary key of the entity to get</param>
    /// <returns>Entity</returns>
    public TEntity Get(TPrimaryKey key)
    {
        return Session.Get<TEntity>(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts a new entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">Entity</param>
    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        Session.Save(entity);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates an existing entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">Entity</param>
    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        Session.Update(entity);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes an entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Id of the entity</param>
    public void Delete(TPrimaryKey id)
    {
        Session.Delete(Session.Load<TEntity>(id));
    }
}
```

Everything works corret when I Insert a entity.
Update is onyl working when I add a Session.Flush() to my Update method.

This is the mehtod which is called from Ajax and performs insert or update.

```
 [Authorize]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public JsonNetResult CreateOrUpdateTimeRecord(TimeRecord tr)
    {

        TimeRecord trLocal;
        if (tr.Id == -1 || tr.Id == 0)
        {
            trLocal = new TimeRecord();

            trLocal.Description = tr.Description;
            trLocal.StartTime = tr.StartTime;
            trLocal.EndTime = tr.EndTime;

            trLocal.User = _userRepo.Get(tr.User.Id);
            trLocal.Hdt = _hdtRepo.Get(tr.Hdt.Id);

            _timeRepo.Insert(trLocal);
        }
        else
        {
            trLocal = _timeRepo.Get(tr.Id);

            trLocal.Description = tr.Description;
            trLocal.StartTime = tr.StartTime;
            trLocal.EndTime = tr.EndTime;

            _timeRepo.Update(trLocal);
        }



        return new JsonNetResult() { Data = trLocal};
    }
```

I dont understand why this works for insert and not for Update.
Do I have to care about transaction and opening/closing Sessions?
I thought that "LifestylePerWebRequest" would do that for me.

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:edit: (my initial answer was partially wrong)

You implementation should actually work fine (just tested it).
Though I can reproduce the behavior that updates are not flushed although the session object gets disposed correctly

The `LifestylePerWebRequest` actually takes care of that just fine, it will dispose the session whenever the request ends. Therefore you had to add the request handle to the web.config etc... So the windsor stuff is perfectly aware of the fact that ISession is disposable and that it has to dispose it...

This is because of the the FlushMode of the session.

The default mode is Auto, which might not be really what you want because you cannot rely on the changes getting stored (especially with update calls).

You can either change the FlushMode of the created session object, or, and this is what I recommend, use transactions.

Lets look at the following example:

```
var session = container.Resolve<ISession>();

var obj = new Paper()
{
    Author = "Author",
    Description = "Description",
};
session.Save(obj);

obj.Author = "Author2";
session.Update(obj);
```

In this case, the update will never be flushed/stored in the database. This is the behavior you currently have I guess.

Now lets add a transaction around it:

```
var session = container.Resolve<ISession>();
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var obj = new Paper()
    {
        Author = "Author",
        Description = "Description",
    };
    session.Save(obj);

    obj.Author = "Author2";
    session.Update(obj);

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Now the changes will be saved for sure.

Comment: I've tried UoW based on the following article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543810/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Of-Work-using-Castle#Repositories

but this causes a problem with lazy loading.

Comment: As far as I understand UoW it can't be compatible with LazyLoading since I close and commit my Session when the mehtod I marked with the UoO attribute finishes.
In my case I then access a property in Razor and it is completely clear to me that the session can’t be open anymore.
But I'm new to all that stuff so please correct me if I'm wrong with that.

Currently I'm testing the approach in the link you posted.
Seems to work,
but still testing 

Comment: Wouldn't it be the easiest way to mark the contoller mehtod with a UoW attribute?

Comment: But I have one more question because I want to understand that stuff. In my initial implementation (code posted above) I registered my ISession like that: Component.For<ISession>().UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).LifestylePerWebRequest()
I already asked myself where this Session is closed and flushed and thought that the framework will handle that for me and that I control that with the “PerWebRequest()” call.
But this seems not to be the case since I have to flush my session in my Update method of repository.
Can you please help me understand that?

Comment: Just to be clear. When I say I markt the method with a UoW attribute I mean that I have an aspekt implemented which incepts a "Open" at the beginnging and an "Flush, Close, Dispose" at the end.

Comment: Hey, sorry for confusing you a lot, I finally tested the code you provided a little bit more and read some documentation and your code was actually just fine. The reason for the issue is the flush mode. See my updated answer (I will delete all other comments to clean this up a little bit)

Comment: Many thanks!
I think I will stay with the HttpModule and LazySessionContext as described in the link you provided since this works like a charme.
Just one more thing... What do you think about adding my UoW -attribute to my controller method? Shouldn’t this also fit perfectly in Webscenarios?
You told me that you use UoW it by adding the begin/end UoW to an event handler of begin/end request within the global.asax but if I use AOP and incept “BeginTransaction” at the method start and “Commit” to end of method it would give me the possibility to use it only in methods which really need this.